# [Xcode]Does xcodebuild archiving returns status code?

Tags: ios, xcode

Does xcodebuild command returns status code?

I am using xcode 6.0.1 to automate my build & archive process, i want to get the status code from build command and use the status code to proceed to next build step which is archiving.

Comment: Did you try it and see if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`man xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

> Exit Codes
>
> xcodebuild exits with codes defined by sysexits(3).  It will exit with EX_OK on success.  On failure, it will commonly exit with EX_USAGE if any options appear malformed, EX_NOINPUT if any input files cannot be found, EX_IOERR if any files cannot be read or written, and EX_SOFTWARE if the commands given to xcodebuild fail.  It may exit with other codes in less common scenarios.